# Direct descendant not working (>)

Tags: html, css

So the code below is how I want the table to look. But I was wondering if I could achieve the same thing using the direct descendant CSS selector combinator (next code snippet).

```css
.tabs td.line + td.line {
  border-left: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="tabs" style="border-bottom: 5px solid black" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td height="10px">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
        <td valign="center" align="center" style="padding: 10px 0" class="line">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>
                something
              </td>
              <td valign="center">
               something else
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
        <td valign="center" align="center" style="padding: 10px 0" class="line">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>
                something
              </td>
              <td valign="center">
               something else
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
        <td valign="center" align="center" style="padding: 10px 0" class="line">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>
                something
              </td>
              <td valign="center">
               something else
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>        
  </tr>
</table>
```

This doesn't work as expected. Was expecting it to go to first table, find direct descendant `tr` and apply it to direct descendant `td`.

```css
.tabs > tr > td + td {
  border-left: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="tabs" style="border-bottom: 5px solid black" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td height="10px">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
        <td valign="center" align="center" style="padding: 10px 0" class="line">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>
                something
              </td>
              <td valign="center">
               something else
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
        <td valign="center" align="center" style="padding: 10px 0" class="line">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>
                something
              </td>
              <td valign="center">
               something else
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
        <td valign="center" align="center" style="padding: 10px 0" class="line">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>
                something
              </td>
              <td valign="center">
               something else
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>        
  </tr>
</table>
```

Basically wondering only about the css part.

Comment: Any row not in a `<thead>`, `<tbody>`, or `<tfoot>` is implicitly wrapped in a `<tbody>`.

Comment: @Ryan Ah yes, how foolish of me